# Почему сайт работающий на вордпресс, огромное колличество раз обращается сам на себя (тем самым уменьшается производительность)?

Tags: wordpress

Помогите решить задачу.
Есть сайт:
https://evroflag.by/
У него на данный момент небольшая производительность и много раз в сутки отваливается БД.
В хостинге сказали, что проблема в том, что сайт огромное колличество раз обращается сам на себя.
Скриншот ниже:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос:
По какой причине сайт обращается сам на себя?
И главное. В чём кроется данная проблема и как её устранить?

Comment: ну так запросите часть логов, в которых они видят "обратился сам на себя". Подозреваю, что там агент поддержки увидел в аксесс логах, что реферер = ваш же сайт, и решил что это плохо, а не аякс.

Comment: Но если вы в пхп коде где-то делаете запрос к вашему же сайту через хттп, то это крайне странно будет.

Comment: Установи  https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/ Он расскажет больше и понятней.

Comment: @teran Да. Рефер - наш же сайт. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: что исправить? вы с одной страницы сайта переходите на другую по ссылке - получаете что реферер ваш же сайт. Что в этом процессе можно исправить?